# How to take a clean backup from a compromised laptop?

Tags: windows-7, security

My laptop has been infected by malware. How should I take a clean backup from my files on the other drives than C: (OS) to prepare for a clean reinstall?

Comment: Kudos for putting non-OS software on different drives.  Because you've done that, if the files that aren't on C: are clean, you don't need to delete & reinstall them.  If the OS is the only thing infected, just replace the OS.

Comment: thanks mcalex, how can i b sure other drives are not infected?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are (although possible) the malware hasn't infected any files or programs. If there's specific files/documents you wish to backup, then just do it. If you know what you need to save then spend some time gathering them up and saving them to some external source. Then reformat and place the files back on C:

Another suggestion would be to remove the malware, you know.. like people do.

I've sworn by this program for years and years and it never stops surprising me how good of a job it does.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

However use at your own risk. I'm not responsible should you misuse the program or anything goes wrong.

Comment: thanks Farang, for the link. is it the tool to scan other drives for the malessoftware? it is better to be done before reinstall or after it?

Comment: Tanks alot everyone, apparently Icould recover my laptop using several antimaleware and without doing a reinstall. but still i am curious how to take clean backup of the other drives than C: when the systm is infected? pls suggest. thanks to all.